# не переводит на главную страницу с помощью заголовка header

Tags: php, header

// главная  `index.php`

`creat.php` отправка данных с помощью этого кода на `index.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Create Task</h1>
      <form action="store.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="content" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
$pdo =  new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysite","root","");

$sql = 'INSERT INTO dates(title, content) VALUES (:title, :content)';

$statement =  $pdo->prepare($sql);

$statement->bindParam(":title",$_POST['title']);

$statement->bindParam(":content",$_POST['content']);

$result =  $statement->execute();


header("Location: /");exit();
```

как сделать так, чтоб при отправке данных, сразу переводил на `index.php`

главная страница находится по адресу `http://localhost/mysite/index.php`

Comment: header('Location: http://localhost/mysite/index.php');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тэге `<form>` в атрибуте `action` указывается обработчик, который будет принимать и обрабатывать данные из формы.
Т.е. `<form action="index.php" method="post">` перенаправит на index.php вместе с данными формы, которые попадут в `$_POST` массив.